# Is "those" used as an anaphor or a deictic?

Tags: pronouns, anaphora

The following is from an essay titled "['DOUBLE SUFFERING' WHEN WOMEN TARGETED NOT ONLY FOR GENDER BUT ALSO FOR RELIGION](https://www.sightmagazine.com.au/7150-essay-double-suffering-when-women-targeted-not-only-for-gender-but-also-for-religion)":

> A year ago, a special conference focusing on this issue heard how women are being increasingly targeted as a deliberate strategy to rob them of their faith and their identity.
>
> Records of women being systematically targeted in order to undermine "opposing" groups, in both armed conflict and inter-communal tension, stretch back millennia.
>
> From dictating rules by which "other" women must live, through to sexual assault and forced pregnancy, prostitution and marriage, the power of this targeting is clear: women who survive are injured, traumatised and shamed.
>
> **Those** enduring sexual violence may then be ostracised from their community.

In the last sentence, "those" seems to mean not just "those people" but "those women".

If so, is "those" used as an anaphor or a deictic?

Comment: It's anaphoric and is understood from "women" (the antecedent) earlier in the narrative as meaning "those women". Deixis is quite different. It has to do with the act of utterance: the time/place/participants, i.e. those with the role of speaker or addressee. In speech, deictic expressions are often accompanied by indexing acts performed by the speaker in order to identify their reference. If "those" was deictic in your example it would have to be uttered by the speaker and would typically be accompanied by pointing with fingers, head or other body parts. But that is clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

**Those** here means **those women** and it is an example of the **deictic** use. 
It is not an **anaphor** as it has no antecedent in the sentence. But it can be  an example of **endophora** as it refers to 'the women' mentioned elsewhere in the text.

> In linguistics, **[deixis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis)** refers to words and phrases, such as
>   “me” or “here”, that cannot be fully understood without additional
>   contextual information -- in this case, the identity of the speaker
>   (“me”) and the speaker's location (“here”). Words are deictic if their
>   semantic meaning is fixed but their denotational meaning varies
>   depending on time and/or place. Words or phrases that require
>   contextual information to convey any meaning – for example, English
>   pronouns – are [deictic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis).
>
> In linguistics, [anaphora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics))  is the use of an expression whose
>   interpretation depends upon another expression in context (its
>   antecedent or postcedent). In a narrower sense, anaphora is the use of
>   an expression that depends specifically upon an antecedent expression
>   and thus is contrasted with cataphora, which is the use of an
>   expression that depends upon a postcedent expression. The anaphoric
>   (referring) term is called an [anaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)).
>
> For example, in the sentence **Sally arrived, but nobody saw her**,
>   the pronoun her is an anaphor, referring back to the antecedent Sally.
>
> [Endophora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endophora) refers to the phenomenon of expressions that derive
>   their reference from something within the surrounding text
>   (endophors).
>
> For example, in the sentences **"I saw Sally yesterday. She was lying
>   on the beach"**, "she" is an endophoric expression because it refers
>   to something mentioned elsewhere in the text, i.e. "Sally".

Comment: In "I saw Sally yesterday. She was lying on the beach", why can't you say "she" is an anaphor? I mean, what's the difference between this example and the earlier one?

Comment: 'She' has no antecedent in the sentence. In a strict sense an anaphor takes its meaning from its antecedent. 'Sally' can be the antecedent, but in a different sentence; such a scenario is called 'endophora'.

Comment: "Sally" is the logical antecedent of "she".